Why is the graph not displayed in full?
I have this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    %axis equal,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    domain=-8:8,   % Ajuste del dominio
    samples=100,
    width=8cm,
    grid=both, % Activa cuadrícula para divisiones principales y secundarias
    minor grid style={dashed, gray!20}, % Estilo de la cuadrícula secundaria
    major grid style={solid, gray!50},  % Estilo de la cuadrícula principal
    xmin=-8, xmax=8,  % Ajuste de límites del eje x
    ymin=-8, ymax=8,  % Ajuste de límites del eje y
    tick label style={font=\tiny}, % Cambia el tamaño de los números en los ejes
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    legend cell align={left}
]

% Gráfica de x^3 en rojo
\addplot[red, thick] {x^(1/3)};
\addlegendentry{$f(x)=x^3$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}

But the function x^(1/3), doesn’t show properly. It is kind of cut off. This is what I intended:


Unfortunately this code snippet can’t compile. Please correct. A screenshot might help to see your issue more easily. Thank you

I think now you can compile it

Like this?

Edit:
From your question is not clear, is this result is what you looking for. Showed desired result of your MWE is like above diagram, but in comments and legend you write that you like to draw function of third order.
In proposed solution I assume that you after showed above diagram. It present third root of absolute value of independent variable x.
As you write your function in code: x^{(1/3), you should be aware, that pgfplots do not know to draw imaginary function which it become on domain between -8 and 0, so I assume (regarding to desired result of compilation showed in your question), that should be declared as abs(x)^(1/3).
That this function can be drawn near zero, I changes settings of samples which now also define function domain:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=8cm,
        axis lines=middle,
        axis equal,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},       
%
        xmin=-8, xmax=8,
%        ymin=-3, ymax=3,
        ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, fill=white, inner sep=2pt},
%
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
%
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
        major grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!50},
        minor tick num=4,
%
        legend pos=north east,
        legend style={font=\scriptsize},
%
        samples at={-8,-7.5,...,-1,-0.999,-0.998,...,0, 0.001, 0.002,...,1,1.5,...,8},
   ]

% Gráfica de x^3 en rojo
\addplot[red, thick] {abs(x)^(1/3)};
\addlegendentry{$f(x)=x^{1/3}$}

\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}

